# I use kivy python I want to change the text on other screens

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

***I learn to write program
I use kivymd python.
The problem is
I do multiple screens And then I want to change the text at some where and make the text at the same where on the other screen change as well, but as I did in the code snippet, it only changed the screen I edited.

thank***

main.py

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivymd.app import MDApp

class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass
class SecondScreen(Screen):
   pass

class Example(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file('main.kv')

Example().run()
```

main.kv

```
ScreenManager:
    MainScreen:
    SecondScreen:
<MainScreen>:
    name:"Main"
 
    MDRoundFlatButton:
        text: "Change"
        text_color: 1, 0, 0, 1
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5,"center_y": .2}
        on_release: my_output.text = my_input.text
            
    MDTextField: 
        id:my_input
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5,"center_y": .4}
        size_hint:.5,.1
        hint_text:'input'

    MDRoundFlatButton:
        id:my_output
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5,"center_y": .3}
        text:'apple'#here
        text_color: 1, 0, 0, 1

    MDRoundFlatButton:
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5,"center_y": .5}
        text: "ChangeScreen"
        text_color: 1, 0, 0, 1

        on_release: app.root.current = "Second"

<SecondScreen>:
    name: "Second"
    
    MDRoundFlatButton:
        text: "ChangeScreen"
        text_color: 1, 0, 0, 1
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5,"center_y": .5}

        on_release: app.root.current = "Main"

    MDRoundFlatButton:
        id:my_output
        text:'apple'#here too
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5,"center_y": .4}
        text_color: 1, 0, 0, 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the `SecondScreen` through the `ScreenManager`. And, in the `MainScreen`, you can access the `ScreenManage` using the `manager` property. So, you can accomplish what you want by modifying your `Change` `Button` like this:

```
MDRoundFlatButton:
    text: "Change"
    text_color: 1, 0, 0, 1
    pos_hint: {"center_x": .5,"center_y": .2}
    on_release:
        my_output.text = my_input.text
        root.manager.get_screen('Second').ids.my_output.text = my_input.text
```